# I can't install SQL Server on my PC

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a PC with Windows XP Professional x64.

And I'm trying to install a SQL Server Express x64 version. All goes well until the setup builder try's to set the necessary setup files.

At this point I receive the following error:

> *SQL setup has encountered the following error: 
>
>   MsiGetProductInfo failed to retrieve Product version for package with product code = {A2122A9C-A699-4365-ADF8-68FEAC125D61} Error code: 1605.*

I really don't know what's the issue here. Is there anybody how can assist me?

Comment: which version of SQL Server?

Comment: And what edition? Where did you download the installer from?

Comment: Have you tried Googling it? A search for "sql setup error code 1605" returns loads of results

Comment: The version is 2008 R2 x64

Comment: Download it from the official SQL web site.

Comment: check the [prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.105).aspx) - particularly the footnote for "Framework" and "Software"

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 cannot be installed on Windows XP if I'm not mistaken (and which is also documented in the link swasheck posted)

Comment: Wrong Windows XP Professional accepts SQL server 2008 R2 I just did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://slecluyse.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/sql-server-2008-r2-error-code-1605/):

> This record of Windows Installer error codes on MSDN lists 1605
> incorrectly as an indicator for not enough free space available on the
> target drive; [DesktopEngineer.com](http://desktopengineer.com/windowsinstallererrorcodes) however, states that 1605 designates
> a missing product, required to complete a custom action successfully:
> 1605 ERROR_UNKNOWN_PRODUCT This action is only valid for products that
> are currently installed.

The solution that the link provides is this.

**> Solution**

> Trial and error to the rescue.
> So by means of elimination,> the following simple solution appears to be fairly effective.
>
> Delete the registry key’s parent containing 56A968A049C8C7F45A7C79D2C3C8DEE9
> in HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer\UpgradeCodes.
>
> In this particular case, deleting the 7AB711B11CB5E91428E0D7F4F314C2B7 key first (GUID transformation), results
> in a successful installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 afterwards:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\UpgradeCodes\7AB711B11CB5E91428E0D7F4F314C2B7]
> "56A968A049C8C7F45A7C79D2C3C8DEE9"=""
>
> Microsoft often moves in mysterious ways.

How to transform the GUID very simply?

see here:

> 1. Run Registry Editor (type regedit in Start Search or Run dialog box and press enter) and navigate to-
>    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes
> 2. Take the first part of GUID and reverse it, in my case it is AA4A4B2C and its reverse string is C2B4A4AA. Now search for C2B4A4AA
>    and you’ll get a match than delete the its parent subkey (it will be a
>    kind of GUID without braces).
> 3. Now run the Setup again, it will go smoothly without any hassle.

See this [link](http://www.windowsvalley.com/fix-sql-server-setup-has-encountered-the-error-code-1605/) about the solution

Comment: Finally I kill 10 GUID's :) Thanks